# Specifying a default base, other than 10, for numeric column fields in result set output for MySQL clients?

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table, let's call it `Permissions`, with numeric columns `UserId` and `Privilege`. The `UserId` column is considered to be a decimal value, but `Privilege` is supposed to be a hexadecimal value. The hexadecimal values are better for privilege codes (because every privilege bit is responsible for the flags like R, W, X and so on), and this is widely used by us for the `INSERT` statements using the hexadecimal literals, e.g.:

```
INSERT INTO `Permissions` (`UserId`, `Privilege`) VALUES (12, 0x53);
```

Let's assume that `3` in `0x53` is a flag mask standing for encoded privilege actions, so a person who read such an `INSERT` statement can easily understand that this permission grants R(1) and W(2) permissions. But when the query to the `Permissions` table is executed, e.g. in native MySQL client, the privilege value is shown as decimal (please assume `SELECT * FROM`):

```
+--------+-----------+
| UserID | Privilege |
+--------+-----------+
|     12 |        83 |
+--------+-----------+
```

Is there a way to recommend MySQL clients to *display* (not return as strings) some numeric columns in hexadecimal view **by default**? It probably might be somewhere in table metadata, hmmm, "recommendations" or somewhere in clients configs - honestly, I have no any idea on that. Another reason of why this is useful is that it could be possible to use simple `SELECT * FROM` query not applying the `HEX()` function for a certain column every time you invoke the query, where `HEX()` even changes the result set column type from number to string.

Any ideas? Your help would be really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

---

*P.S. I'm not sure if this question should be asked here. If a better place is at SuperUser or Database Administrators, please migrate. Thanks!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that a VIEW would be what you want.  Just select all of the columns, specifying HEX(Permissions) as Permissions, and tell clients to use the view instead of the table.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html

Comment: Thank you for the interesting reply, I didn't consider that, because it's not exactly what I'm looking for, but I'll keep your suggestion in mind. + I'm not really sure about the data type for such a column in the view: in your scenario it becomes a string instead of a number. Anyway, thanks again.

Comment: HEX is inheritly a string type.  It is a representation of binary.  The binary is the binary, and then you can interpret it as an base10 int, or a base16 int, an ascii letter, etc.  I don't believe "return a value as a HEX Number" makes sense.

Comment: The reason is that I wouldn't like to have a result set containing a string column just as a representational view of a numeric column. But for the just-to-read/watch debugging and internal purposes a view with the `HEX()` function applied is fine. Thanks.